# Get a function argument's default value?

Tags: python

For this function

```
def eat_dog(name, should_digest=True):
    print "ate dog named %s. Digested, too? %" % (name, str(should_digest))
```

I want to, external to the function, read its arguments and any default values attached. So for this specific example, I want to know that `name` has no default value (i.e. that it is a required argument) and that `True` is the default value for `should_digest`.

I'm aware of `inspect.getargspec()`, which does give me information about arguments and default values, but I see no connection between the two:

`ArgSpec(args=['name', 'should_digest'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(True,))`

From this output how can I tell that `True` (in the `defaults` tuple) is the default value for `should_digest`?

Additionally, I'm aware of the "ask for forgiveness" model of approaching a problem, but unfortunately output from that error won't tell me the name of the missing argument:

```
>>> eat_dog()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: eat_dog() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

To give context (why I want to do this), I'm exposing functions in a module over a JSON API. If the caller omits certain function arguments, I want to return a specific error that names the specific function argument that was omitted. If a client omits an argument, but there's a default provided in the function signature, I want to use that default.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

### Python3.x

In a python3.x world, you should probably use a [`Signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature) object:

```
import inspect

def get_default_args(func):
    signature = inspect.signature(func)
    return {
        k: v.default
        for k, v in signature.parameters.items()
        if v.default is not inspect.Parameter.empty
    }
```

### Python2.x (old answer)

The args/defaults can be combined as:

```
import inspect
a = inspect.getargspec(eat_dog)
zip(a.args[-len(a.defaults):],a.defaults)
```

Here `a.args[-len(a.defaults):]` are the arguments with defaults values and obviously `a.defaults` are the corresponding default values.

You could even pass the output of `zip` to the `dict` constructor and create a mapping suitable for keyword unpacking.

---

looking at the docs, this solution will only work on python2.6 or newer since I assume that `inspect.getargspec` returns a *named tuple*.  Earlier versions returned a *regular tuple*, but it would be very easy to modify accordingly.  Here's a version which works with older (and newer) versions:

```
import inspect
def get_default_args(func):
    """
    returns a dictionary of arg_name:default_values for the input function
    """
    args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
    return dict(zip(args[-len(defaults):], defaults))
```

Come to think of it:

```
    return dict(zip(reversed(args), reversed(defaults)))
```

would also work and may be more intuitive to some people.

---

Comment: @Tadeck -- I had to upvote yours.  I was just guessing how those could be combined until I saw your post which confirmed my suspicions.

Comment: @Tadeck could you explain how this works? I'm a bit perplexed at what's going on.

Comment: @skyler -- do you know the `zip` function?  What part don't you understand.  I'll happily improve the answer if you can tell me what's confusing to you.

Comment: @mgilson I think I get it now. Args with default values cannot be interspersed with args without default values, so mapping the default values to the args list, starting at the last argument and moving backwards, correctly connects the two.

Comment: @skyler -- Precisely.  I couldn't have stated it nicer myself.

Answer (score 13):

Depending on exactly what you need, you might not need the `inspect` module since you can check the `__defaults__` attribute of the function:

```
>>> eat_dog.__defaults__
(True,)
>>> eat_dog.__code__.co_argcount
2
>>> eat_dog.__code__.co_varnames
('name', 'should_digest')
>>> 
>>> eat_dog.__kwdefaults__
>>> eat_dog.__code__.co_kwonlyargcount
0
```

Comment: (How) can you tell from this which parameter the default `True` corresponds to?

Answer (score 12):

To those looking for a version to grab a specific default parameter with [mgilson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627202/5332072) answer.

```py
value = signature(my_func).parameters['param_name'].default
```

Here's a full working version, done in Python 3.8.2

```py
from inspect import signature

def my_func(a, b, c, param_name='apple'):
    pass

value = signature(my_func).parameters['param_name'].default

print(value == 'apple') # True
```

Comment: How does it work if I have more default params?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `inspect` module with its [`getargspec` function](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec):

> `inspect.getargspec(func)`
>
> Get the **names and default values of a Python function’s arguments**. A `tuple` of four things is returned: `(args, varargs, keywords, defaults)`. **`args` is a list of the argument names** (it may contain nested lists). `varargs` and `keywords` are the names of the `*` and `**` arguments or `None`. **`defaults` is a tuple of default argument values** or `None` if there are no default arguments; if this tuple has `n` elements, they correspond to the last `n` elements listed in `args`.

See [mgilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627202/548696) for exact code on how to retrieve argument names and their default values.

Comment: *Deprecated since 3.0*, so actually already deprecated for 4 years at the time this answer was written.

Answer (score 2):

to take care of keyword-only args (and because defaults and kwonlydefaults can be `None`):

```
spec = inspect.getfullargspec(func)
defaults = dict(zip(spec.args[::-1], (spec.defaults or ())[::-1]))
defaults.update(spec.kwonlydefaults or {})
```

Comment: Yep.  +1 for pointing this out.  My original answer was written before python3.x was all that popular.  It turns out there's even a _better_ way to handle this now with Signature objects (which I've added to my original answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can get this via some of the `__dunder__` vars as mentioned by other posts. Putting that into a simple helper function can get you a dictionary of default values.

- `.__code__.co_varnames`: A tuple of all input variables
- `.__defaults__`: A tuple of the default values

  - It is worth noting that this tuple only incudes the default provided variables which must always be positioned last in the function arguments

You can use these two items to match the last n variables in the `.__code__.co_varnames` with all the items in the `.__defaults__`

EDIT Thanks to @griloHBG - Added if statement to prevent exceptions when no defaults are specified.

```
def my_fn(a, b=2, c='a'):
    pass

def get_defaults(fn):
    if fn.__defaults__==None:
        return {}
    return dict(zip(
        fn.__code__.co_varnames[-len(fn.__defaults__):],
        fn.__defaults__
    ))

print(get_defaults(my_fn))
```

Should give:

```
{'b': 2, 'c': 'a'}
```

Comment: Why the minus 1 with no explanation?

Comment: `__defaults__` is a list of strings that has `len` equals to amount of arguments with default values. Since in Python arguments with default values must always be the last ones, using `-` on `len` of `__defaults__` (with the `:` to get until the end of the array) will bring up the argument names (from `co_varnames`) that have default values. BUT the function `get_defaults` will fail if `fn` has no arguments with default values. Checking on `len` of `__defaults__` would be helpful to prevent errors: if `__defaults__`'s `len` is zero then return.

Comment: Thanks. Although there is an issue if you need to capture the rest of kwargs. Will add padding to the right. ```def my_fn(a, b=2, c='a', **others):```

Answer (score 0):

In python, all the arguments with default value come after the arguments without default value. So the mapping should start from the end till you exhaust the default value list. Hence the logic:

```
dict(zip(reversed(args), reversed(defaults)))
```

gives the correctly mapped defaults.