# Append to default parameter of function

Tags: python

is it possible to append to a default function parameter or to get the value of the function parameter from outside?

for example:

```
def foo(bar, foo="baz"):
    print(bar, foo)

foo("hello", "world") # print "hello world"
foo("hello", foo="world") # print "hello world" as well
foo("hello") # print "hello baz"
foo("hello", foo<append it>"bla") # how? want to print "hello bazbla"
print("default value of foo's foo parameter:", [magic here])
```

i dont think this is a good practise but I'm curious.

Comment: What's wrong about calling `foo("hello", "bazbla")`? Do you want to modify the function itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a function argument's default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627118/get-a-function-arguments-default-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> foo.__defaults__
('baz',)
```

The `__defaults__` attribute
is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

---

So, to alter the foo parameter using the default value, you could use string formatting:

```
foo("hello", foo="{}bla".format(foo.__defaults__[0]))
```