# Catching messages passed to unit tests

Tags: python, wrapper, python-unittest, python-decorators

I am developing a Django backend for an online course platform. When a student submits code for grading, the backend runs unit tests (using the `unittest` library) and returns to the frontend the message returned by the failed test.

After much help from ChatGPT, I can catch the message passed to the assertions by using the following wrapper:

```py
def save_custom_message(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MyTests.msg = kwargs.get('msg', '')
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)            
    return wrapper

class CustomTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if name.startswith("assert") and callable(attr):
            return save_custom_message(attr)
        return attr
```

Here is the usage:

```py
class MyTests(CustomTestCase):
    def test_division(self):
        self.assertEqual(10 / 2, 5, msg="First division assert")
        self.assertEqual(10 / 2, 3, msg="Second division assert")
        self.assertEqual(10 / 5, 2, msg="Third division assert")

def run_unit_tests(test_class):
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_class)

    for test in suite:
        result = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(test)
        if not result.wasSuccessful():
            for failure in result.failures:
                return MyTests.msg
    return True

result = run_unit_tests(MyTests)
if result is True:
    print("All tests passed!")
else:
    print(f"Test failed: {result}")
```

This works just fine. But now I would like to be able to pass a message to the test function:

```py
class MyTests(CustomTestCase):
    def test_division(self, msg="Something is wrong with division"):
        self.assertEqual(10 / 2, 5)
        self.assertEqual(10 / 2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(10 / 5, 2)
```

My understanding was that `test_division` was a method of MyTests just like `assertEqual`. Therefore, I tried simply testing for the prefix `test`:

```py
class CustomTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    default_message = "The test case failed"
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if (name.startswith("assert") or name.startswith("test")) and \
           callable(attr):
            return save_custom_message(attr)
        return attr
```

However, I got the error:

`TypeError: save_custom_message.<locals>.wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

This suggests that my understanding is wrong. I would very much appreciate an in-depth explanation of the issue and a suggestion on how to fix it.

P.S. An additional confusion I would be happy to resolve is that, when I tried printing `args` for `self.assertEqual(10 / 2, 3, msg="Second division assert"), only 3 would be printed, but 5 would not. This suggest that the first argument does not seem to be passed. I would be happy to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have researched the topic. As explained in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055710/2725810), the main problem with my approach is that the default keyword arguments are not passed into the wrapper.

This works:

```py
import unittest
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature

def save_custom_message(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        MyTests.msg = signature(func).parameters['msg'].default
        return func(*args, **kwargs)            
    return wrapper

class CustomTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if name.startswith("test") and callable(attr):
            return save_custom_message(attr)
        return attr

class MyTests(CustomTestCase):
    def test_division(self, msg = 'my message'):
        self.assertEqual(10 / 2, 5)
        self.assertEqual(10 / 2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(10 / 5, 2)

def run_unit_tests(test_class):
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_class)

    for test in suite:
        result = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(test)
        if not result.wasSuccessful():
            for failure in result.failures:
                return MyTests.msg
    return True

result = run_unit_tests(MyTests)
if result is True:
    print("All tests passed!")
else:
    print(f"Test failed: {result}")
```