# How to get the expected parameters of another function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I would like to know if it is possible, given a function (as an instance, or a string), to get its paramaters, if defined default values for each paramater and, if possible, the type of each parameters (probably using the type of default value, if defined) in Python 3.5.

## Why would you want that ?!

Long story short, I am generating a XML file containing details of different functions in my project. Since the generator has to be future-proof in case someone modifies, add, or delete a function, the next generated file must be updated. I succesfully retrieved the functions I wanted either as instance or a string of the code calling it.

I have two solutions (well, more the beginnings of solutions) to solve this problem, using `inspect` and `jedi`.

### Inspect

Using `inspect.signature(function)`, I can retrieve the name and default values of all the parameters. The main issue I see here, would be analyzing this function:

```
def fct(a=None):
    # Whatever the function does...
```

Analyzing the type of the default value will lead to misunderstandigs. Is there a way to fix that ?

### [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi)

Jedi is an extremely powerful tool, maybe even too much ! Getting the function in a one line code string, and analyzing it through Jedi gives an extraordinary amount of information, that I am lost with to be completely honest. Plus, I might get bad autocompletion (example: instead of having the paramaters for `print`, I might get autocompleted to `println`)

If someone had used one of these tools for this prupose, or even better if you know a better, more "pythonic" way of doing this, I would be really grateful !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627118/get-a-function-arguments-default-value

Comment: You could use [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for this, but the question seems too broad for SO generally.

Comment: @DanielMessias Thanks, I haven't find this in my research, since I did not only require default values I guess. Still, won't I encounter an issue with ′def fct(a=None)′ ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't have the right to change all the functions of the project unfornately. Type hints would solve everything in my case!

Comment: I don't understand the question. `inspect` does what you describe in the preamble of your question. Then you say you tried `inspect` but claim "Analyzing the type of the default value will lead to misunderstandigs". This is where you lose me. What's wrong with `None`?

Comment: @timgeb Analyzing the type of `None` will determine that the paramater would like a variable of type "NoneType", while it might be entirely something else. I can simply add a if statement to manage this case, yet I wanted to see if a solution allowed me to determine the "best" type possible for this parameter. It's probably impossible, but you never know !..

Comment: @superpg ah, den just juse type hints, maybe leveraging the `typing` module.