# Using a variable that is shared across multiple modules as a default function argument

Tags: python

The issue at hand is best illustrated with this minimal example containing 3 scripts:

**foo.py**

```
global_val = [0]
```

**bar.py**

```
from foo import global_val

def work(val=global_val[0])
    print("global_val: ", global_val[0])
    print("val: ", val)
```

**main.py**

```
from bar import work
import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo.global_val[0] = 1
    work()
```

**What I expect the output to be:**

```
global_val: 1
val: 1
```

**Actual output:**

```
global_val: 1
val: 0
```

I don't understand why the default argument for `val` in `bar.py` isn't `1`. I'm confused because I clearly update `global_val` before calling `work()`, but for some reason the old value is still used as the default function argument.

It seems that the default argument is somehow pre-computed when `global_val` is imported in `bar.py`. Isn't Python code supposed to be dynamically compiled at run-time?

I'm using Python 3.6, if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is that `def work(val=global_val[0]):` is evaluated at import time (e. g. when `from bar import work` is hit in `main.py`.)  The default arguments for a function in Python are evaluated at the moment the function [is *defined*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) and stored in its `signature` ([here's how you can inspect them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627118/get-a-function-arguments-default-value)).

Thus, the order of operations is:

1. Run `main.py`
2. `from bar import work`
3. Locate and load `bar`
4. `from foo import global_val`
5. Locate and load `foo`
6. `def work(val=global_val[0]):`
7. Construct a function called `work` and evaluate its default parameters (`global_val[0] == 0`)
8. `foo.global_val[0] = 1`
9. Invoke `work`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, what is going on is that at the moment you are importing work func from bar.py, the default argument is executed, and doesn't matter if you change the value later, because the default argument was already "declared" on the import, since the default arguments are evaluated just once

Answer (score 0):

```
item = 0

def bar(val=item):
    print(val)

bar(2)  # 2
bar()  # 0
item = 1
bar()  # 0
```

This is something to do with default arguments, not globals. Default arguments are evaluated *once*, not each time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

As defaults are fixed at the time of definition/import you would be best setting a flag or None as the default and testing for that flag at the head of the function where you can then assign an object, from available scope (of course), at execution time as the actual default you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think when the the compiler sees this:

```
def work(val=global_val[0])
```

the default value of val will be what global_val[0] were at that time. Setting it to something different later on will not change the function definition, i.e. set the val variable to 0 (which is the first element of global_val) if no argument for that parameter is supplied.

Try something like this instead:

```
def work(val=None):
  if not val:
    global global_val
    val = global_val[0]
```

Here you set val to something known that you can catch, None in this case, and then set the proper value. Using the keyword global makes sure you use the variable from the global namespace. This will sett the correct value of global_val if it's changed later on after the function definition is compiled.