# Python: explicitly use a function's default arguments

Tags: python, default-arguments

Under normal circumstances one calls a function with its default arguments by omitting those arguments. However if I'm generating arguments on the fly, omitting one isn't always easy or elegant. Is there a way to use a function's default argument explicitly? That is, to pass an argument which points back to the default argument.

So something like this except with `~use default~` replaced with something intelligent.

```py
def function(arg='default'):
  print(arg)

arg_list= ['not_default', ~use default~ ]

for arg in arg_list:
  function(arg=arg)

# output:
# not_default
# default
```

I don't know if it's even possible and given the term "default argument" all my searches come up with is coders first tutorial. If this functionality is not supported that's ok too, I'd just like to know.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I think it should be possible to instantiate a [`partial` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects) dynamically. Have a look at [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: If you are generatimg arguments on the fly don't you have a value for all arguments? Why can't you just use them?

Comment: Does your target function have only 1 argument which can take many values?   If you really need to dig at the target function and if you dont know them ahead of time or dont own that function, maybe check out **inspect** module.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627118/get-a-function-arguments-default-value

Comment: This is a *very* unpythonic thing to do, it's why functions with complex argument lists use named-association (kwargs) that each have defaults. Then you only pass the args you want to override the default value for (makes *"omitting one arg easy and elegant"*). Does that satisfy your use-case? Then rewrite your code. If not, and if the function's under your control, then make the default of each kwarg `None`, per @wim's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such feature in Python. There are hackarounds, but they're not very likable.

The simple and popular pattern is to move the default into the function body:

```
def function(arg=None):
    if arg is None:
        arg = 'default'
    ...
```

Now you can either omit the argument or pass `arg=None` explicitly to take on the default value.

Comment: Though this does assume that `None` can never be a valid argument.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general purpose way to omit an argument; you can specialize to particular functions by explicitly passing the appropriate default value, but otherwise, your only option is to fail to pass the argument.

The closest you could come is to replace your individual values with `tuple`s or `dict`s that omit the relevant argument, then unpack them at call time. So for your example, you'd change `arglist`'s definition to:

```
arg_list = [{'arg': 'not_default'}, {}]
```

then use it like so:

```
for arg in arg_list:
    function(**arg)
```

A slightly uglier approach is to use a sentinel when you don't want to pass the argument, use that in your `arg_list`, and test for it, e.g.:

```
USEDEFAULT = object()
arg_list = ['not_default', USEDEFAULT]

for arg in arg_list:
    if arg is USEDEFAULT:
        function()
    else:
        function(arg=arg)
```

Obviously a bit less clean, but possibly more appropriate for specific use cases.

Comment: The sentinel is exactly what I would have suggested.