Call function within a function but keep default values if not specified
I have two sub functions that feed into one main functions as defined below:
Sub function 1:
def func(x=1, y=2):
    z = x + y
    return z

Sub function 2:
def func2(a=3, b=4):
    c = a - b
    return c

Main function:
def finalFunc(lemons, input1, input2, input3, input4):
    result = func(input1, input2) + func2(input3, input4) + lemons
    return result

How do I call my main function but if the values for the sub functions aren't specified, they're treated as default? Similarly, if they are specified, then use them instead, e.g.
>>> finalFunc(lemons=1)
3

or
>>> finalFunc(lemons=1, input1=4, input4=6)
4

I don't want to specify the default values in my main function, as the sub functions are always changing. I want to keep the default values set at whatever the sub functions contain.

I assume that you don't have the authorizaton to modify the sub-functions given to you because if you have full control over the entire source code you would specify default values for the main function instead, and make parameters for the sub-functions mandatory without defaults.

A situation where the requirement can easily arise is when there are some library functions which should have optional/default arguments, and a CLI which plumbs into those same library functions and needs to render defaults in the --help output. In such cases making the sub-function arguments mandatory isn't an option because that's an API change.

@wim Exactly. In the high likelihood that the sub-functions are library functions the OP cannot/should not modify them, which is why I'm assuming the OP is looking for a solution to set the default values of the parameters of the main function to be the same as the library functions without modifying them.

That is not necessarily the best approach, because if you need to monkeypatch some different values during test, now you have to patch them in two different namespaces (because function defaults are evaluated at import time).

@wim That's a valid point. I've updated my answer with a solution that doesn't copy the default values of the sub-functions then.

My recommendation:
def func(x=None, y=None):
    if x is None:
        x = 1
    if y is None:
        y = 2
    z = x + y
    return z

def func2(a=None, b=None):
    if a is None:
        a = 3
    if b is None:
        b = 4
    c = a-b
    return c

def finalFunc(lemons, input1=None, input2=None, input3=None, input4=None):
    result = func(input1, input2) + func2(input3, input4) + lemons
    return result

It is low-tech, but it is DRY and creates no unnecessary coupling between the func, func2 and finalFunc. The simple if arg is None: idiom is familiar to most Python developers, and doesn't come with any weird surprises.
I've attempted more "clever" approaches in the past, such as sharing the defaults in module level globals, or digging values out from func.__defaults__ to re-use, but the downsides always seem to outweigh the advantages.

I'm not sure if the question can be understood as a duplicate, but at least your answer is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684249/python-explicitly-use-a-functions-default-arguments

@mkrieger1 That one was unfortunately an XY question, but it does look like a duplicate of the Y part  :)

In case you don't have the authorization to modify the sub-functions given to you, you can set the default values of parameters of the main function to None (or a different sentinel value if None is a valid value for the sub-functions), and make the main function call the sub-functions with a helper function that binds values to the respective arguments only if they are not None, with the help of inspect.signature:
from inspect import signature

def func(x=1, y=2):
    z = x + y
    return z

def func2(a=3, b=4):
    c = a - b
    return c

def call(func, *args, **kwargs):
    return func(**{
        name: value
        for name, value in signature(func).bind(*args, **kwargs).arguments.items()
        if value is not None
    })

def finalFunc(lemons, input1=None, input2=None, input3=None, input4=None):
    result = call(func, input1, input2) + call(func2, input3, input4) + lemons
    return result

Demo: https://ideone.com/SS005G

You could consider pulling your variables out as global variables - this would resolve your current issue, increase verbosity, and allow you to use the same variables in other locations.
GLOBAL_A = 1
GLOBAL_B = 2
GLOBAL_C = 3
GLOBAL_D = 4

def func1(a=GLOBAL_A, b=GLOBAL_B):
    return a+b

def func2(c=GLOBAL_C, d=GLOBAL_D):
    return c-d

def func3(f, a=GLOBAL_A, b=GLOBAL_B, c=GLOBAL_C, d=GLOBAL_D):
    return func1(a,b) + func2(c,d) + f


Note - I am note entirely sure how Python-Specific developers view global variables, but if this is the approach you intend to take, it should be noted that general coding practices would recommend against performing any mutable operations on your global variables. It is primarily a method of placing variables you intend to modify prior to runtime in a convenient location.

The OP specifically said they don't want to default the main function arguments.

@OysterShucker That is not how I understood the OP requirements. I think they just don't want to duplicate default values in two different places. This answer is a reasonable solution.

@OysterShucker "I don't want to specify the default values in my main function, as the sub functions are always changing. I want to keep the default values set at whatever the sub functions contain."
This would place defaults in the main function, but eliminates the concerns related to it (Variables changing in the sub function without changing in the main function). This centralizes the location in which the code needs to be modified - which is one of the more prominent uses for global variables.

I'm getting different results for your examples, but I think they're correct.
finalFunc(lemons=1)   # (1+2) + (3-4) + 1 = 3
finalFunc(lemons=1, input1=4, input4=6)   # (4+2) + (3-6) + 1 = 4

And the code builds kwargs for sub-funcions according to a mapping of names. The downside is it does not accept positional args. finalFunc(1,3,5,7,9) will not work.
f1_map = {'input1': 'x', 'input2': 'y'}
f2_map = {'input3': 'a', 'input4': 'b'}
def finalFunc(lemons, **kwargs):
    f1_kwargs = {mk:kwargs[k] for k,mk in f1_map.items() if k in kwargs}
    f2_kwargs = {mk:kwargs[k] for k,mk in f2_map.items() if k in kwargs}
    # optional: raise an error for unknown kwargs
    result = func(**f1_kwargs) + func2(**f2_kwargs) + lemons
    return result




You're right, my apologies. Have edited OP. Couldn't get it to work so used my brain with the example, which clearly is failing me
