# In python, how to obtain the default parameter of a function within the decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

I have built a series of functions and a decorator as follows:

```
def check_param(func):
    def wrapper(param):
        # check the param
        check(param)
        # then run the function
        return func(param)
    return wrapper

@check_param
def func_a(param='a'):
    print(param)

@check_param
def func_b(param='b'):
    print(param)
```

The parameter `param` of the functions has different default values, and I need to check them before running `print(param)`. However, sometimes the functions use default parameter, then how can I check the value of the parameter used in the functions before running it.

**Update**

I know the package `inspect` can get the default values of the parameters. However, if I wrap the function with a decorator, `inspect` only can get the default settings of the decorator (like the decorator `check_param`) rather than the function `func_a`. So it cannot solve my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a function argument's default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627118/get-a-function-arguments-default-value)

Comment: @SuperStormer, thanks, but it doesn't work because if I use a decorator `checkparam` with the function `func_a`, `inspect` or `func_a.__defaults__` return the setting of the decorator `check_param` rather than `func_a` (the output is `param` with `None` as the default value, but what I want is `param` with `"a"` as the default value).

Comment: You never return the wrapper. This replaces all your functions with None

Comment: "However, if I wrap the function with a decorator, inspect only can get the default settings of the decorator (like the decorator check_param) rather than the function func_a" Did you try using it *inside the code for the decorator*? You know, where you have access to the variable `func`, which stores the original function, and not the decorator (nor a decorated version of the function)? How exactly *did* you try to use it? What you describe should only happen if you try to use `inspect` *on the decorated function after the fact*, but that defeats the purpose of using the decorator anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The default arguments for a function are stored in its `__defaults__` and `__kwdefaults__` attributes (see here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). Both are writable, so you can copy them over like this:

```
def check_param(func):
    def wrapper(param):
        # check the param
        check(param)
        # then run the function
        func(param)
    wrapper.__defaults__ = func.__defaults__
    wrapper.__kwdefaults__ = func.__kwdefaults__
    return wrapper
```

You can do it even cleaner using [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), but the default `assigned` will need to be updated with the attributes you want in addition to the usual `WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS`:

```
from functools import wraps, WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS

def check_param(func):
    @wraps(func, assigned=WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS + ('__defaults__', '__kwdefaults__'))
    def wrapper(param):
        # check the param
        check(param)
        # then run the function
        func(param)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Note, assigning `__defaults__` and `__kwdefaults__` will not do anything useful for most decorators. For most decorators, where the wrapper's signature looks something like `def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): ...` instead of matching the original function's signature, any `__defaults__` and `__kwdefaults__` you set on the wrapper will be ignored. The wrapper will never use them, and the original function will use its original defaults.

Comment: @user2357112. Correct, which is why those attributes don't appear in `WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS` by default. But OP's case is special in that they will actually do exactly what is wanted and expected. You can actually ignore `__kwdefaults__` entirely in this case.