# Python variable value for default argument

Tags: python

In Python, what value can a variable take, so that when a function is invoked with the variable as an argument, the function uses its default value for the parameter instead?

Consider the following code:

```
def foo(a=100):
    print(a)

b = None #blank value
foo(b)
```

*Desired output:*
100

*Actual output:*
None

I hypothesized that None would work, but clearly it doesn't. What value can I choose for b, so that foo(b) is equivalent to foo()? Or is this simply not possible? I'm in a situation where the value for b can either be defined, or I would like to use the default value of the parameter.

Comment: you could do `foo(100)`

Comment: I would like to be able to change the default value only one place and for it to still work

Comment: But you're not using the default, you're actively telling it to use a different value instead of the default.

Comment: You could do something like `def foo(a=None)` and then in the first line of the function: `if a is None: a=100`

Comment: to use the default value, call the function without passing the arg, e.g. `foo()`

Comment: `foo.__defaults__[0]`

Comment: @khelwood Assuming the function *has* a `__defaults__` attribute. (A function defined in C may not have one.)

Comment: `int` is kind of a good example; it's not "obvious" that `int()` and `int(0)` should be the same. (OK, it's *kind of* obvious, but that's more a property of knowing what `int` does rather than of how it is defined.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This answer assumes that you cannot modify `foo`, and that you cannot use reflection or introspection to determine what the default argument value is.)

---

It's the *absence* of an argument, not any particular value used as an argument, that triggers the use of the default value. The only way you can produce nothing out of something is to unpack an empty mapping

```
foo(**{})
```

or an empty sequence

```
foo(*())
```

Both `*` and `**` are part of the function-call syntax, though, not part of the argument value, so with a variable, it still looks like

```
b = {}
foo(**b)

b = ()
foo(*b)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `None` to revert to a default value, the easiest way is to do the logic in the function itself.

```
def foo(a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = 100
    print(a)
```

Comment: Better to keep a=100 in function params to keep showing the intention of the function (and also keep your additional code).

Answer (score 0):

Function default parameter uses when there don't pass any parameter for the argument. And None is not a blank value. None is an object of NoneType Datatype in python similar to Other Datatype Object.

Instead, you can use

```
def foo(a=100):
    a=100 if a is None else a //Ternary operator 
    print(a)

b = None #blank value
foo(b)
```

Output:
100

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I ended up using the inspect module to create a helper function which extracts the default values of the function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627202/19449892):

```
import inspect

def get_defaults(func):
    signature = inspect.signature(func)
    return { k: v.default for k, v
             in signature.parameters.items()
             if v.default is not inspect.Parameter.empty }


def foo(a=100):
    print(a)

b = get_defaults(foo)['a']
foo(b)
```

*Output:*
100

Comment: May I ask *why* you did this? That's an awful lot of work to do something equivalent to simply not passing the value at all. It works, sure, but so does making a `dict` and only adding the mapping for `"a"` if you have a non-default, then unconditionally doing `foo(**mydict)`. I suspect [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Making a `dict` with all the parameters and unpacking it is probably a more elegant solution, but it does turn a single line function call into multiple lines of creating an argument `dict`, checking for which arguments should be added (we're talking upwards of 20), and finally the function call itself, with unpacking arguably being a less familiar operation to novice python developers.

Comment: I'll grant you it's a multiline thing, but then, any reasonable case for "do I want to use the default or not?" is also going to be multiline. I won't grant the unpacking argument; it's a key skill to learn, more important than `inspect`-based reflection code, and novice Python developers that want to become even journeymen need to learn it at some point.