# ufunc created with frompyfunc in numpy python will not work if argument with a default value is omitted

Tags: python, numpy

I made a simple function in python and I would like to use it now with **numpy arrays**. The function has an argument with a default value that can therefore normally be omitted. However, when using frompyfunc, omitting the default argument will not work. Why? And how can the original function be used then with numpy.arrays?

```
import numpy as np.array

# define a simple f with 2 args, one of them defaults to 1
def my_func(x, y=1):
    return x + y

# create ufunc to work with arrays
# refer to original my_func, declare 2 inputs (x and y), 1 output (x + y)
my_ufunc = np.frompyfunc(my_func, 2, 1)

# Call the ufunc with 2 arguments (all will work)
print(my_ufunc([1, 2, 3], 1))
print(my_ufunc([1, 2, 3], [1]))
print(my_ufunc([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]))

# Call the ufunc with 1 positional argument, omit the 2nd for which a default
# value was previously defined
# but it will not work :(
print(my_ufunc([1, 2, 3]))
```

TRACEBACK:
TypeError: my_func (vectorized)() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 1 were given

Comment: Don't expect the function returned by `frompyfunc` to handle defaults.  You told it to expect  2 arguments.  Give it 2!  In fact, none of the compiled `ufunc` take a default like that.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html - explains the arguments that a ufunc can take.

Comment: Understood! functions that are made to work with numpy arrays with frompyfunc will not work in the typical way of a python function i.e. no default values will be read, all arguments must be explicit. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy has overloaded all the arithmetic operators on numpy arrays (+, -, *, /, etc....), you just need to convert your `list` to a numpy array to use those operators.

```
import numpy as np

def my_func(x, y=1):
    return x + y

lst1 = [1,2,3]
arr1 = np.array(lst1)  # convert list to numpy array
arr2 = np.array([3,4,5])  # define and convert list to numpy array
print(my_func(arr1, arr2))
print(my_func(arr1))
```

```
[4,6,8]
[2,3,4]
```

you can check [numpy quickstart](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations) and  [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a view on how numpy overrides a lot of operations for you.

---

as for you main issue, `np.frompyfunc` creates a wrapper function that just inspects and replicates the number of arguments, but doesn't inspect the default arguments, but you don't/shouldn't need to use it anyway as it is much slower (and longer) than using numpy's overloaded operators.

**Edit**: an implementation of `np.frompyfunc` that supports default arguments will look as follows, **this is unoptimized and lacks a lot of error checking and ability to handle positional-only arguments**, and i must cite [Get a function argument's default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627118/get-a-function-arguments-default-value)

```
import numpy as np
import functools
import inspect

def get_default_args(func):
    signature = inspect.signature(func)
    return {
        k: v.default
        for k, v in signature.parameters.items()
    }

def numpyfrompyfunc(func):
    default_args = get_default_args(func)
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        new_kwargs = {}
        for i, (key,value) in enumerate(default_args.items()):
            if i < len(args):
                new_kwargs[key] = args[i]
            else:
                if key in kwargs:
                    new_kwargs[key] = value
                elif value is not inspect.Parameter.empty:
                    new_kwargs[key] = default_args[key]
                else:
                    raise ValueError(f"parameter {key} unfilled")
        max_length = 0
        kwarg_sizes = {}
        for key,value in new_kwargs.items():
            if hasattr(value, "__len__"):
                max_length = max(max_length, len(value))
                kwarg_sizes[key] = len(value)
            else:
                kwarg_sizes[key] = 1
        outputs = []
        for i in range(max_length):
            kwargs_single = {}
            for key,value in new_kwargs.items():
                if kwarg_sizes[key] == 1:
                    kwargs_single[key] = value
                else:
                    kwargs_single[key] = value[i]
            outputs.append(func(**kwargs_single))
        return np.array(outputs)
    return wrapper


def my_func(x, y=1):
    return x + y

new_func = numpyfrompyfunc(my_func)
lst1 = [1,2,3]
lst2 = [3,4,5]
print(new_func(lst1 , lst2 ))
print(new_func(lst1 ))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ahmed AEK, I did not know that was possible. I realize however that I might have oversimplified my question. What would happen if the function is more complex? I will post a new question with a more complex function.

Comment: Well this just tackles the example, but does not solve the underlying problem. Assume the function was not `+`. How would you write a ufunc function that takes a default value.. I perceive thats what you were to respond to

Comment: @Onyambu check the edit, you can by my guest at implementing one that is optimized, does error checking, and supports positional only arguments.

Comment: This is amazing!